# how does array[100] = {0} set the entire array to 0?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

How does the compiler fill values in `char array[100] = {0};`? What's the magic behind it?

I wanted to know how internally compiler initializes.

Comment: In C or C++?  They are two separate questions.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

It's not magic.

The behavior of this code in C is described in section 6.7.8.21 of the C specification ([online draft of C spec](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)): for the elements that don't have a specified value, the compiler initializes pointers to NULL and arithmetic types to zero (and recursively applies this to aggregates).

The behavior of this code in C++ is described in section 8.5.1.7 of the C++ specification ([online draft of C++ spec](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf#subsection.8.5.1)): the compiler aggregate-initializes the elements that don't have a specified value.

Also, note that in C++ (but not C), you can use an empty initializer list, causing the compiler to aggregate-initialize all of the elements of the array:

```
char array[100] = {};
```

As for what sort of code the compiler might generate when you do this, take a look at this question: [Strange assembly from array 0-initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531477/strange-assembly-from-array-0-initialization/531490)

Comment: Do all C compilers do this? I was lead to believe only Visual Studio does this.

Comment: online draft of c++ specs broken, anyone has new link?

Answer (score 35):

Implementation is up to compiler developers.

If your question is "what will happen with such declaration" - compiler will set first array element to the value you've provided (0) and all others will be set to zero because it is a default value for omitted array elements.

Comment: I don't have a source, but I'm pretty sure that I read somewhere that there is no default value for array declarations; you get whatever garbage was already there. There's no sense in wasting time setting these values when you're likely to overwrite them anyway.

Comment: Ryan, if you don't set a value for the first element that the whole array is uninitialised and indeed contains garbage, but if you set a value for at least one element of it the whole array becomes initialised so unspecified elements get initialised implicitly to 0.

Comment: For C++ an empty initializer list for a bounded array default-initializes all elements.

Comment: dalle, I'm not into c++ so my response was about c.

Comment: qrdl, i think dalle (and me too, btw) read it as you would say "char a[100] = {}" would leave it uninitialized. but actually it is only valid in C++, and invalid syntax in C.

Comment: Well, I didn't mean that. {} is an empty initialiser (invalid in C, as you pointed out) so quite obviously it will initialise the array.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Implementation of `char array[100] = {0}` is *not* undefined. See the above answer by @bk1e.

Comment: @NatanYellin Where did I say that this is undefined? Please read the full answer before commenting and downvoting.

Comment: @qrdl You're right. I misunderstood your comment about the implementation. Unfortunately, I can't change my vote now.

Answer (score 28):

If your compiler is GCC you can also use following syntax:

```
int array[256] = {[0 ... 255] = 0};
```

Please look at
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits, and note that this is a **compiler-specific** feature.

Comment: Welcome! since you asked for Looking more such sorts of tricks, I had provided

Comment: You certainly can do this if you choose, but there are obvious disadvantages to relying on compiler-specific extensions like this one.

Comment: @Dan Olson his question himself is asking about compiler specific and hence posted this. If you feel it is useless, i will delete.

Comment: It's not useless, it's interesting.  The caveat just deserves to be noted.

Comment: It's stuff like this keeps me coming back to SO and reading more than the top few answers...

Comment: Note that this may work for gcc and not g++. This doesn't work for me with g++ 6.2.0

Answer (score 19):

It depends where you put this initialisation.

If the array is static as in

```
char array[100] = {0};

int main(void)
{
...
}
```

then it is the compiler that reserves the 100 0 bytes in the data segement of the program. In this case you could have omitted the initialiser.

If your array is auto, then it is another story.

```
int foo(void)
{
char array[100] = {0};
...
}
```

In this case at every call of the function foo you will have a hidden memset.

The code above is equivalent to

```
int foo(void)
{ 
char array[100];

memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));
....
}
```

and if you omit the initializer your array will contain random data (the data of the stack).

If your local array is declared static like in

```
int foo(void)
{ 
static char array[100] = {0};
...
}
```

then it is technically the same case as the first one.