# Does setting some fields of an array, set the others to zero?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

```
int main()
{
    int b[2][3]={{1,2},{3,4,5}};
    cout << b[0][2] << endl;
}
```

And the result in both visual and g++ is `0`! Why? I thought it must be another number!
For example, when we define `int a[5]` then we say `cout << a[3];` without setting `a[3]`, it will be something like, 0123984283 which means the last value of this cell in the RAM.

But here, What's the reason of `0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is **Partial Initialization**, yes rest of the elements are guaranteed to be 0.

Here is a good read for Standerdese Fans and ones with eye for detail:

[**C and C++ : Partial initialization of automatic structure**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828294/c-and-c-partial-initialization-of-automatic-structure/10828333#10828333)

Comment: What do you mean by Partial Initialization?

Comment: @MiladR: Please read the linked answer, it explains in detail, why and how.

Comment: *Partial initialization* is not a term of C++, it is the term that someone used to ask a question. The term (for what is referred in the link as partial/full initialization) is **aggregate initialization**, and there is no specific term for *aggregate initialization* where not all of the fields are mentioned in the initializer list.

Answer (score 1):

This answer has a more complete explanation with references to the documentation:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/629063/475523