# Initialise data member array elements to zeros on VS2012?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a class Y which contains an array of size 100 X objects.

```
class Y{
    unsigned int x_array[100];
};
```

I need to initialise this array so that all the elements are zero. Is it this possible to do in Visual Studio and if not what can I do? If I do:

```
unsigned int x_array[100] = {0};
```

I get a compile error saying data member initialisation is not allowed.

(Intel C++ Compiler v13)

Comment: As far as I know data member initialization is a C++11 feature that uses a similar syntax. If you are not using C++11 features, check if there is a compiler setting to force targeting an older standard maybe?

EDIT: this is just a wild guess, I havent done any C++ in ages

Comment: you could always put `x_array()` in the initializer list of the constructor. (and have been able to since vs2010, i believe).

Comment: @LostSalad I have a feeling this is one feature of C++11 VS2012 doesn't implement.

Comment: @user997112 yeah, but it's pretty arb. I'd expect it to work seeing as you can use a similar array initializer for local variables. See question from 2009: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629017/how-does-array100-0-set-the-entire-array-to-0

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is available only since C++11, in C++03 the following should do:

```
class Y{
public:
    Y() : x_array() { }
    unsigned int x_array[100];
};
```

Also consider using `std::vector<unsigned int>` instead:

```
#include <vector>

class Y{
public:
    Y() : x(std::vector<unsigned int>(100, 0)) { }
    std::vector<unsigned int> x;
};
```

Comment: +1. In case the OP is wondering where the first one comes from, C++11 § 8.5,p5-7 *are* implemented in VS since 2010, though you may have to squelch their "Hey, you're using a new 03x feature, just in case you didn't know that." warning. (The warning number escapes me. sry). Edit: I have no idea if Intel's CC can do this, but judging by [this feature list](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c0x-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler) I'd be surprised if they don't. and note, v14 does support non-static initializers, so maybe an upgrade is in order.