# Initialization lists in arrays

Tags: c++

So, if I do this:

```
int a[5];
```

The array will contain garbage values.

If I do this though:

```
int a[5] = {};
```

It will now contain all zeros even though we didn't really initialize any of those values with 0s.

So, what's happening here?

Comment: If don't specify any value in { } then it will take default value i.e 0.

Comment: What's happening??? Exactly what you said is happening.

Answer (score 2):

see this for more info: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

> By default, regular arrays of local scope (for example, those declared within a function) are left uninitialized. This means that none of its elements are set to any particular value; their contents are undetermined at the point the array is declared.
>
> But the elements in an array can be explicitly initialized to specific values when it is declared, by enclosing those initial values in braces {}. 
>   The initializer can even have no values, just the braces:
>
> `int a[5] = { };`
>
> This creates an array of five int values, each initialized with a value of zero

Comment: So, if I do the same for a set of chars, will it take default values of chars? And what is a default value for a char?

Comment: For array of chars if you do not specify any value in the braces, the default value will be '\0'.

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing it with 0's.

Similarly,

```
int a[5] = {1};
```

would mean that the first element is initialized with a 1, and the rest with 0's.

Answer (score 0):

`int a[5];` requests a contiguous block of memory sufficient to store 5 integers but does not perform any initialization.

`int a[5] = {};` requests a contiguous block of *zero initialized* memory sufficient to store 5 integers.

See this SO [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629017/how-does-array100-0-set-the-entire-array-to-0).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "what's happening"? You just told us what's happening.
The second example zero-initialises the values, whereas the first does not!

> It will now contain all zeros even though we didn't really initialize any of those values with 0s.

Yes, you did, by writing `= {}`. That's what it means.