# How all the elements of array initialize to zero and first element to 1 in c

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

Here is the program the array automatically initialize to zero and first element initialize to 1 when declare as int arr[10]={1}

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int arr[10]={1};
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d",arr[i]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

how array elements are initialized to zero expect the first element?

Comment: It will hep you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629017/how-does-array100-0-set-the-entire-array-to-0

Comment: your question is changed? any how following @sourav answer applicable to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array elements are initialized based on the initialization rule for aggregate type with initialization lists, as specified in C standard.

It mentions, if there are less number of initializers supplied in the brace-enclosed list than that of the number of element in the aggregate type, the **remaining** elements in the aggregate type will be initialized with the value as if they have `static` storage duration, i.e., a value of 0.

To quote `C11`, chapter §6.7.9, *Initialization* (emphasis mine)

> **If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate**, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, **the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.**

and regarding the initialization of variables having `static` storage duration,

> [..] If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, then:
>
> - [...]
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
> - [...]

So, very rightly, in your case

```
  int arr[10]={1};
```

`arr[0]` is having a value `1`, `arr[1]` to `arr[9]` all are set to `0`.