# Is it allowed to initialize array recursively?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, array-initialization

I have the following code snippet:

```
int i[] = {42, i[0]};
```

Is such initialization allowed or leads to undefined behaviour?

Three major compilers (gcc, clang, msvc) give me `42` for `i[1]`. Hence looks legit, but I would like to see a cite from the standard for this case.

Comment: It's legit in C. Array members are initialized from the beginning. So you even can: `int i[] = { [1] = func(i[0]), [0] = 5 };`

Comment: Found some tips on this forum.. in this case a reference to the array itself is not needed, you could also initialize the whole array using a single value 42, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629017/how-does-array100-0-set-the-entire-array-to-0

Comment: @Goodies `you could also initialize the whole array using a single value 42` Would you mind to show how?

Comment: Read the topic I linked. This is valid C++ syntax: char array[100] = {42};  (note you will have to specify the array length in the declaration..)

Comment: @Goodies in this case all the rest elements will be zeroes.

Comment: Ah I've tested it, you're right.. I've only looked at the opening.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is well-defined.

```
int i[] = {42, i[0]};
```

This is an *aggregate<sup>1</sup> initialization<sup>2</sup>*. Aggregate initialization observes this rule:

> #### [`[dcl.init.aggr]/6`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#6)
>
> The initializations of the elements of the aggregate are evaluated in the element order. That is, all value computations and side effects associated with a given element are sequenced before those of any element that follows it in order.

---

<sup>1)</sup> http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#1

<sup>2)</sup> http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#3