# clearing a char array c

Tags: c, arrays, char

I thought by setting the first element to a null would clear the entire contents of a char array.

```
char my_custom_data[40] = "Hello!";
my_custom_data[0] = '\0';
```

However, this only sets the first element to null.

or

```
my_custom_data[0] = 0;
```

rather than use `memset`, I thought the 2 examples above should clear all the data.

Comment: Jared, why did you set the c++ tag? he talked about "C" and did not add any C++ related tags.

Comment: This applies equally well to character arrays in C++, even though he didn't specify.

Comment: I've removed the C++ tag to avoid what we've already seen with people offering C++ specific solutions

Answer (score 128, accepted):

It depends on how you want to view the array.  If you are viewing the array as a series of chars, then the only way to clear out the data is to touch every entry. `memset` is probably the most effective way to achieve this.

On the other hand, if you are choosing to view this as a C/C++ null terminated string, setting the first byte to 0 will effectively clear the string.

Comment: They key word in the answer is 'effectively'. Only the first element is begin set to 0 and the rest still have undefined values but if you are treating the array as a null terminated string and the first element is null, then the string is considered empty.

Comment: indeed, this is the answer folks.

Comment: @caparcode, exactly.  That's why it's very important to understand how the array is being used.

Comment: Yes, that is what I should have said in my first post. The char is a terminated string. so either these will do that trick. char[0] = '\0'; or char[0] = 0. I am not sure but I heard that using '\0' is better for using null terminated strings.

Comment: @robUK, yes you are correct. Technically '\0' is equal to 0 (in ascii) but you should use '\0' because it makes your intention clear

Comment: About "most effective" - please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453432/difference-in-initalizing-and-zeroing-an-array-in-c-c/455137#455137

Comment: you do understand that in ANSI C (atleast) the array[] = {0}; construct only works when you define an array and when you try to do it later on you get a compile error!

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it makes more sense to me now. But if the char array is printed using `fprintf` will it print only up to the Null pointer? Or will it print the rest of the junk inside the array?

Comment: oh, this is really old... oh well

"clear the string" requires more definition here.

the c functions that look at strings assume that if they find a '\0' character (null) then that is the end of the string.  That's the definition of "null terminated string"

oh, this is really old....oh well

So if you make the first character of a char array a null character, you have a  zero-character (empty) null-terminated string.

Whatever else is in the array is irrelevant.

Answer (score 82):

An array in C is just a memory location, so indeed, your `my_custom_data[0] = '\0';` assignment simply sets the first element to zero and leaves the other elements intact.

If you want to clear all the elements of the array, you'll have to visit each element. That is what `memset` is for:

```
memset(&arr[0], 0, sizeof(arr));
```

This is generally the fastest way to take care of this. If you can use C++, consider std::fill instead:

```
char *begin = &arr;
char *end = begin + sizeof(arr);
std::fill(begin, end, 0);
```

Comment: I believe the second version should be:
std::fill( arr, arr+ sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]), 0 );

Comment: Clarification: don't use sizeof with fill because you'll get in trouble later with arrays of int, long, double or what have you.

Comment: I prefer: std::fill(&arr[0], &arr[arr_len], 0);

Comment: Zan Lynx, that's undefined behavior. you cannot do &arr[arr_len]. but you have to do  std::fill(arr, arr + sizeof arr, 0); or if you have the length somewhere std::fill(arr, arr + arr_len, 0); assuming an array of char

Comment: It is valid only in C . although the question clearly targetted C (another guy added a C++ tag, i've no clue why), the std::fill shows C++ affinity :)

Comment: About "fastest" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453432/difference-in-initalizing-and-zeroing-an-array-in-c-c/455137#455137

Comment: @John, you forgot a "&" before arr[0] . Please review the change i made (added it) and decide whether or not to change it to  "char *begin = arr;" instead (probably you just forgot to remove the "[0]" ?). wanted to add/remove as least characters as possible :)

Comment: pro tip: use the following macro to get an accurate array size whatever the type may be `#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))`

Comment: and why just not `memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));`?

Comment: ARRAY_SIZE(a) will return the size of the pointer, not the size of the array itself.

Answer (score 27):

Why would you think setting a single element would clear the entire array?
In C, especially, little ever happens without the programmer explicitly programming it.  If you set the first element to zero (or any value), then you have done exactly that, and nothing more.

When initializing you can set an array to zero:

```
char mcd[40] = {0}; /* sets the whole array */
```

Otherwise, I don't know any technique other than memset, or something similar.

Comment: I guess this depends on the compiler you use

Comment: @cocoafan:  No, it is not compiler dependent.  It is part of the language specification.  Any compiler that behaves differently is not following the C language.

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you. I couldn't find any resource where I can read this special case. Would be nice to have it as a bookmark.

Comment: It is called partial initialization.  I don't have the C99 spec, but here are two sources:

http://bit.ly/enBC2m  "You do not need to initialize all elements in an array. If an array is partially initialized, elements that are not initialized receive the value 0 of the appropriate type."

http://bit.ly/f9asHH  "If there are fewer initializers than elements in the array, the remaining elements are automatically initialized to 0"

Comment: This does not apply to an array that has already been declared and assigned values does it?

Answer (score 12):

Use:

```
memset(my_custom_data, 0, sizeof(my_custom_data));
```

Or:

```
memset(my_custom_data, 0, strlen(my_custom_data));
```

Comment: The second option (`memset(my_custom_data, 0, strlen(my_custom_data));`) will only clear out to the first '\0', which could be beyond the end of the array. This may, or may not, be okay.

Comment: The first option worked fine on an ESP32, after I tried a lot of other things.

Answer (score 10):

Try the following code:

```
void clean(char *var) {
    int i = 0;
    while(var[i] != '\0') {
        var[i] = '\0';
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI - indent code by 4 spaces or select it and hit the 'code' button, which looks like two lines of binary.

Comment: Excellent solution if you don't wanna include string.h for memset().

Answer (score 7):

Why not use `memset()`? That's how to do it.

Setting the first element leaves the rest of the memory untouched, but str functions will treat the data as empty.

Comment: Don't use memset over readability: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453432/difference-in-initalizing-and-zeroing-an-array-in-c-c/455137#455137

Comment: and what is your answer then?

Answer (score 6):

Pls find below where I have explained with data in the array after case 1 & case 2.

```
char sc_ArrData[ 100 ];
strcpy(sc_ArrData,"Hai" );
```

Case 1:

```
sc_ArrData[0] = '\0';
```

Result:

```
-   "sc_ArrData"
[0] 0 ''
[1] 97 'a'
[2] 105 'i'
[3] 0 ''
```

Case 2:

```
memset(&sc_ArrData[0], 0, sizeof(sc_ArrData));
```

Result:

```
-   "sc_ArrData"
[0] 0 ''
[1] 0 ''
[2] 0 ''
[3] 0 ''
```

Though setting first argument to NULL will do the trick, using memset is advisable

Answer (score 5):

I usually just do like this:

```
memset(bufferar, '\0', sizeof(bufferar));
```

Answer (score 4):

Nope. All you are doing is setting the first value to '\0' or 0.

If you are working with null terminated strings, then in the first example, you'll get behavior that mimics what you expect, however the memory is still set.

If you want to clear the memory without using memset, use a for loop.

Comment: I say no on the for loop.  Try not to write your own "improved" (and usually not) library functions.  In fact, memset and memcpy are rather special are often inlined into custom machine code for the CPU based on what is known about data alignment and length.

Comment: @Zan the OP doesn't want to use memset (perhaps he's embedded and doesn't have it available).  But yes, memset is usually highly optimal, and likely faster than a for loop.

Comment: True, however he didn't want to use memset, so I suggested a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You should use memset.  Setting just the first element won't work, you need to set all elements - if not, how could you set only the first element to 0?

Comment: memset shouldn't be used over readability: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453432/difference-in-initalizing-and-zeroing-an-array-in-c-c/455137#455137

Answer (score 2):

Writing a null character to the first character does just that.  If you treat it as a string, code obeying the null termination character will treat it as a null string, but that is not the same as clearing the data.  If you want to actually clear the data you'll need to use memset.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought by setting the first element
>   to a null would clear the entire
>   contents of a char array.

That is not correct as you discovered

> **However, this only sets the first
>   element to null.**

Exactly!

You need to use memset to clear all the data, it is not sufficient to set one of the entries to null.

However, if setting an element of the array to null means something special (for example when using a null terminating string in) it might be sufficient to set the first element to null. That way any user of the array will understand that it is empty even though the array still includes the old chars in memory

Comment: Don't use "memset" over readability: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453432/difference-in-initalizing-and-zeroing-an-array-in-c-c/455137#455137

Answer (score 1):

set the first element to NULL. printing the char array will give you nothing back.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
bzero(my_custom_data,40);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
void clearArray (char *input[]){
    *input = ' '; 
}
```

Comment: This is not CLEARING, it is just setting first character to ' '! I think you wanted to write *input = '\0'

Answer (score -4):

Try the following:

```
strcpy(my_custom_data,"");
```