# clear contents in char**

Tags: c, char

For the life of me I can't figure out how to do this.  I thought I could use `memset()` but I'm getting a segmentation fault.

```
char **a;
token = strtok( NULL, " " );
if( token != NULL )
    strcpy( token, strtok( token, "\n" )); // get rid of '\n' at end if it exists
else{  
    // I want to reset all the values in a to null 
    return;
}
```

I thought I could even just do a while loop like `while(a[i] != 0 )` set each element to 0, but even then I'm getting a segmentation fault.  This should be easy right?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `a` doesn't have any memory allocated.  Is this the correct code sample?

Comment: how is `char **a;` allocated\set?

Comment: There are no "values in `a`"; all you have is a pointer to nowhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632846/clearing-a-char-array-c

Comment: provide the complete code

Comment: sorry a is allocated elsewhere

Comment: How it could be allocated else where and it's defined here ?! Please provide the complete code this will avoid you to get many questions and remarks

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here.  Yes of course my code confused everyone.  I apologize.  I'm still in my infancy here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial call to strtok() should NOT be done with a NULL argument as the first parameter!

Check the reference:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry I posted just the segement of code that wasn't working.